# iPhone, sqlite3, how can I determine is a table exists already in a few lines of code as possible?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

How can I determine in a table already exists before I start adding data to it again, in as few lines of code as possible?

Comment: Are you using core data, or sqlite3 directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using sqlite directly, you can use the following query to see if the table already exists:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='my_table_name';
```

Comment: Yeah I've seen that just wondered if there was a quicker way or an inbuilt function ?

Answer (score 4):

```
sqlite3_stmt *statementChk;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='util_nums';", -1, &statementChk, nil);

bool boo = FALSE;

if (sqlite3_step(statementChk) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    boo = TRUE;
}
sqlite3_finalize(statementChkUN);
```